# Browser IE11 shows infinite loading status, but IE9 and IE10 is fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am using signalR in my web application for Chatting.signalR version 1.1.4.
it is working fine in chrome and firefox, but it shows continuous loading in IE all versions [in IE9,IE10 nad IE11].
by default Transport Agent used by IE browser is forver frames. firefox and chrome using server sent events.

```
After searching i found that there is loading issue in IE with forver frames.
```

i replaced code in signalR js file suggested by  @JMacPSU.
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/215

after replace @JMacPSU code, works in IE9 and IE10, but still shows continuous loading in IE11. 
Please help me

Comment: Could this be a problem developing with local sites and/or document domain?

Comment: both in local and server

Comment: If it was me, I'd fire up [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and also the dev tools in IE to see exactly if and how the request is being fired and how it's being handled when it gets to the browser.

Comment: i checked with dev tools in IE , request firing is same in all versions , there no issue to trace